# How to check MDI child form is already opened

Tags: vb.net

i have an application that contain `MDI` parent and child form. I have to show the different type of data in grid. so i created a common form with grid and pass the dataset. now how do i check the specific data form is already opened or not. here my code.

```
Public Function FindMdiChild(ByVal Title As String) As Boolean
       If Application.OpenForms.Count = 0 Then Exit Function
       For Each t As Form In Application.OpenForms
           If t.Text.ToString = Title.ToString Then
               t.Activate()
               Return True
           End If
       Next
End Function
```

The problem is some times its stuck on this specific line "`If t.Text.ToString = Title.ToString Then`".

please help me to resole this issue.

Comment: Where is this code located?  Is it in the parent form or elsewhere?

Comment: Its in module class.

Comment: I would suggest [Form.MdiChildren](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.windows.forms.form.mdichildren(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Ian what is the difference?

Comment: This is a duplicate (IMHO) of question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25248253/bring-mdichild-form-to-front-if-already-open (Which I found as the first link when I googled this particular problem -- Maybe next time do a bit more homework) Also, the code is in VB, the c# tag should be removed.